# Issue with mysql time converstion

Tags: mysql, datetime-format

I am trying to read a file to mysql database, there is time column format like this

```
05/20/16 01:54:52.797 AM => month/day/year hours:minutes:seconds.millisecond AM/PM
```

I am using the following code by I can't read it corrrectly

```
Drop table temp;
CREATE TABLE temp LIKE messages;    
load data infile 'C:/xampp/htdocs/gdxg/test_uploads/test.txt' into table temp fields terminated by '\t' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' (@Time, State, Name,Pri,Value,)
SET Time = STR_TO_DATE(@Time,'%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s.%f');
select * from temp limit 10;
```

It doesn't read AM/PM

and if I tried to do so (`@Time,'%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s.%f %p`) just read `null`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](https://i.imgur.com/3ppJhiE.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time. You also have a preview pane right below the editor so you can see how changes look like before you publish them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `hour` specifier wrongly.

**Specifier descriptions**:

1. `'%H'` - for hours in range (00..23)
2. `'%h'` - for hours in range (01..12)
3. `'%p'` - for AM or PM

Change `H` to `h` in your query and use of `'%p'` should be working.

**Example**:

```
mysql> select @t;
+--------------------------+
| @t                       |
+--------------------------+
| 05/20/16 01:54:52.797 AM |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select STR_TO_DATE( @t,'%m/%d/%y %h:%i:%s.%f %p' ) as t;
+----------------------------+
| t                          |
+----------------------------+
| 2016-05-20 01:54:52.797000 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Read Documentation**:

- [**DATE_FORMAT(date,format)**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)